# Tortoise SVN : Accessing Repository in my desktop from another computer

Tags: svn

I have a TortoiseSVN repository created at ip=ab.cde.fgh.123.
I am trying to browse that repository from ip=ab.cde.fgh.124.

I have given "svn://ab.cde.fgh.123/repo" in the address bar for repository from the other machine. But I am unable to browse the repo.

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you set up the `svnserve` server?

Comment: You need to tell us what errors you are getting.

Comment: Can you ping ab.cde.fgh.123 from ab.cde.fgh.123 ?

Comment: yes I can ping ab.cde.fgh.123 from ab.cde.fgh.124

Comment: No I have not set up a svnserve on my desktop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are mainly 3 ways of accessing svn repository files

- file:///C:/svn-repo
- webdav (http://host/path or https://host/path)
- svn://host/path or svn+ssh://host/path

The first method is used to access local files, I mean if the repo is on the local system.

The second and third methods are used when the repo is not on the local machine and you have to contact the remote machine.Although you can set up Apache server on your local machine if you want to access it through webdav.

For the second you need a Apache server running.

For the third you need a svnserver to be installed.

Answer (score 2):

It is likely that you haven't installed and configured the svnserve service that will let you access the files from a remote machine.  [This article explains how to do it](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-serversetup-svnserve.html).

The other option is to use the file:// url to the files which would look something like

```
file:///usr/home/acox/repos/projects
```

which wou
ld allow you to access the files from a remote machine.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use Tortoise, but I routinely access an SVN repository on another computer at home over my network by simply referring to the repository as file://computername/sharename/path, in my case, "file://qwerty/SharedDocs/svn/svnrepos", I believe it is. If that doesn't work for you, post back and I'll verify the details when I get home.